# Visual C++ 2010 comments causing errors

Tags: c++, comments

The `// hi` comment causes red squigglies to appear under `if`, and in the statement below it, `hashTable`, `ItemType*`, and `hashTableSize`. The `if` error is "expected a declaration", the `hashTable` error is "this declaration has no storage class or type specifier", the `ItemType*` error is "expected a type specifier", and the `hashTableSize` error is "identifier 'HashTableSize' is undefined. Removing the comment removes the squigglies. No other class in my project has this issue. What gives?

```
template <class ItemType>
HashedDictionary( const unsigned & p_hashTableSize = DEFAULT_SIZE ) : hashTable( NULL ), hashTableSize( p_hashTableSize ), itemCount( 0 )
{
    // hi

    if ( hashTableSize < 0 )
        throw PrecondViolatedExcep( "Hash table size must be greater than or equal to zero." );

    hashTable = new ItemType*[ hashTableSize ]; 

}
```

Class declaration:

```
#include "HashedEntry.h"

template< class ItemType>

    class HashedDictionary
    {
    private:
        HashedEntry<ItemType>** hashTable;
        unsigned hashTableSize;
        unsigned itemCount;
        static const unsigned DEFAULT_SIZE = 101;

        int getHashIndex( const ItemType & newEntry );
        int computeIndex( const ItemType & newEntry );
    public:
        HashedDictionary( const unsigned & p_hashTableSize );
        bool add( const ItemType & newItem );

    }
```

Comment: I blame IntelliSense.

Comment: Need version visual studios version number.

Comment: MSVC intellisense sucks. If there's no actual compiler error, then you know MSVC really sucks.

Comment: My crystal ball tells me you need a `HashedDictionary::` at the beginning of this, unless it is buried in a class somewhere, which judging by your error messages, I'm thinking not. Is this inline to the class?

Comment: By the way, why are you checking an `unsigned` number for "less than 0", again?

Comment: Note that `//-----------` comment challenges the editor also (at least in VS 2012); the longer the line of hyphens, the more off becomes the editor's idea of writing position.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf thats *awesome*. is that a side effect of their XMLDoc feature?

Comment: @mikhail version number is 10.0.40219.1 SP1 Rel

Comment: Works for me (VS2012)

Comment: @Whoz You're right, I forgot to put that in. Didn't fix the errors though. Not inline.

Comment: @JamesGold I have that studio build on my workstation. I'll give it a shot in a few if this isn't solved by then. Anything special about the class decl? Doesn't look overtly complicated.

Comment: @Whoz I don't believe there is, but I edited it in anyway.

Comment: OK. I see it is a continuation [of this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15870932/homework-implementing-a-hash-dictionary-without-search-keys). Only thing i see odd at all is the lack of a terminating semi-colon after your closing `}` that finishes the class in both sources (this one and the other question), but that is likely just how you copied it (I sure hope it is).

Comment: Tried deleting the no-compile browse database (*.ncb file) and let VS rebuild it?

Comment: What happens when you actually compile the project?

Comment: @Whoz It was the semi-colon. Sigh... But then why weren't there red squigglies until a comment was put in?

Comment: Good question. you ultimately were creating a template function returning an instance of that class, but lord knows beyond that. Not sure its worth the gray-matter at this point. Just glad it works.